# Using map on specific column in list?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I'm trying to split a dataframe in a list of dataframes and then sort each dataframe by a specific variable using `map()`. I thought my approach would work, but I'm obviously not correctly passing something to the function, but I'm unsure as to how to make it work. For instance, using `lapply()` I could do this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df = iris

df %>% 
group_split(Species) %>% 
{lapply(.,function(x) {x %>% arrange(desc(Sepal.Length))})}
```

Using map(), I've tried this approach but it's not working:

```
df %>% 
group_split(Species) %>%
map(.,arrange(Sepal.Length),desc)
```

How can I structure this so it works? I only want to apply the `map()` to one of the columns as in the `lapply()` example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df %>% 
  group_split(Species) %>%
  map(~arrange(.data = .x, desc(Sepal.Length)))
```

or

```
df %>% 
  group_split(Species) %>%
  map(~.x %>% arrange(desc(Sepal.Length)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was simple but I just couldn't find the answer. I will accept asap.

Comment: are you looking for this? `df %>%  group_by(Species) %>%  summarise(Mean = mean(Sepal.Length))`

Comment: try to do this `df %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(across(.cols = starts_with("Sepal"), .fns = mean, .names = "{.col}_mean"))`

Comment: Sorry, so for instance. If I wanted to apply the above using mean function to same column. I thought this would work but it doesn't: `iris %>% group_split(Species) %>% map(~mean(.data = .x, Sepal.Width))`

Comment: `iris %>% group_split(Species) %>% map(~c(mean(.x$Sepal.Width), mean(.x$Sepal.Length)))`

Comment: can you show the expected result?

Comment: So, the expected result in this case would be mean of each species for Sepal.Width. I know that I can use iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(mean = mean(Sepal.Length). But I specifically wanted to apply this to a list of dataframes using map(), thus maintaining structure. Thanks.